# How to read both .xsl and .xlsx using POI?

Tags: xssf

I have tried POI versions 
1.poi-src-3.9-20121203 also with 
2.poi-bin-3.10-beta2-20130904

But not able to read .xls file 
Getting below error 
"
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]"

Note:I am able to read .xlsx file.

Comment: What is the code you have tried? Does xssf support both the formats?  Also this not related to selenium.

Answer (score 0):

**This is for .xlsx**

```
try {            
            // Get the workbook object for XLSX file
            XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(path));
            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wBook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row;
            XSSFCell cell;
            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int count = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    count++;
                    cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();

                        if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                        {
                                 data.append(cell.getRawValue()+ ";");
                        }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
                        {
                            data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ";");
                        } else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                        {
                            data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ";");
                        }  
                        else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                        {
                            data.append("" + ";");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data.append(cell + ";");
                        }
                }
                String finalStr = data.toString().substring(0, (data.length()-1));
               System.out.print(finalStr);
            }

        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Thia is for .xls**

```
try {            
            // Get the workbook object for XLS file
            HSSFWorkbook wBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(path));
            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet) wBook.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFRow row;
            HSSFCell cell;
            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                row = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int count = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    count++;
                    cell = (HSSFCell) cellIterator.next();

                        if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                        {
                                 data.append(cell.getRawValue()+ ";");
                        }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
                        {
                            data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ";");
                        } else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                        {
                            data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ";");
                        }  
                        else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                        {
                            data.append("" + ";");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data.append(cell + ";");
                        }
                }
                String finalStr = data.toString().substring(0, (data.length()-1));
               System.out.print(finalStr);
            }

        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook`. It can be used for both .xls and .xlsx file

```
Workbook workbook = null;
        if (suffix.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
            workbook = (Workbook) new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(
                    new FileInputStream(assetFile)));

        } else if (suffix.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
            InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(assetFile);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);
            inp.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need poi-ooxml to read xlsx format too.
Add this Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

For xls use

```
Workbook  = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("fileName")));
```

For xlsx use

```
Workbook  = workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("fileName")));
```

If you don't know the file format before reading and sometimes finding .xls or .xlsx file extension may not be always good enough to find the actual file format. In that case do like this

```
Workbook workbook;
try {
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("fileName")));
    System.out.println(" Reading XLS file");
} catch (OfficeXmlFileException e) {
    System.out.println(" Reading XLSX file");
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("fileName")));
}
```

Rest is all the same .xls and .xlsx

An easier way to create workbook by autodetecting the input is

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("fileName"));
```